# Do surface temperatures at lower latitudes continue to correlate with frequency of noctilucent clouds in the arctic stratosphere?

Tags: climate-change, climate, clouds, weatherdata, anthropocene

I saw this image in [this answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/3171/6031) to the question [Noctilucent clouds and anthropogenic climate change](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/3114/6031) which was listed as related to the question [“New” cloud types: Can they be used as markers for climate change observations?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/9960/6031).

The answer says:

> In recent observations, reported in the NASA article [Unexpected teleconnections in noctilucent clouds](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2014/16apr_teleconnections/) in 2014 found that the winter air temperature over the USA and Arctic stratospheric conditions have a direct link to the frequency of NLC over Antarctica (as per the image below from NASA):

[image]

At first glance I thought it was an illustration of coincidental correlations until I realized that it's *arctic* and not *antarctic* and so they are in the same hemisphere.

**Question:** But I'm curious, was this still a one-off 45 day coincidental correlation, or has this happened again in 2015 and 2016?